# SoftEther VPN has very slow download, while upload is high

Tags: ubuntu, vpn, softether

I've installed SoftEther VPN Server on Ubuntu 16.0.4.1

VPN clients: iPhone, Windows 8 and another Ubuntu Server

Network Traffic Speed Test Tool:

without VPN:

- Download - **36.88 Mbps**
- Upload - **4.93 Mbps**

with VPN (L2TP or SSTP or SoftEteher VPN client with Local Bridge or SecureNAT):

- Download - **300.53 Kbps**
- Upload - **4.79 Mbps**

from VPN server to another server without VPN (same LAN, 1Gbps):

- Download - **0.95 Gbps**
- Upload - **0.92 Gbps**

from another server to VPN server via VPN:

- Download - **9.14 Mbps**
- Upload - **905.33 Mbps**

  ---
- Download **-only** - **88.18 Mbps**
- Upload **-only** - **0.91 Gbps**

Why Download is very low ?

Comment: For the server to server via VPN test, could you explain a bit more about how you are testing? I am wondering if part of this might not be disk IO, rather than network IO - where is your download file coming from? In general, using a VPN comes with some overhead to account for encryption and various control messages, but that overhead would not, I think, account for your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a problem with Local Bridge (eth0), so I changed it to Local Bridge(tap) + br0(tap + eth0) => issue is fixed

Comment: Could you please provide any details on what exactly was wrong with using just "eth0" and what you did to improve your results?  I think that I have the exact same issue, and it doesn't make sense to me *why* adding a random TAP bridge would fix anything.

Comment: Note on my experience: SoftEther creates its TAP device after it starts, so there's no way to set up the bridging of "eth0" *and* "tap_*" in advance.  I ended up overriding my systemd unit to have an "ExecStartPost" step that runs a script to run "brctl add br0 tap_softether" when that TAP device exists.

Comment: I don't know what caused issue with just "eth0", but as you can see from my Q.  network performance was VERY bad for download.
That's why I played with TAP and found that it performs well.

And yes, I did the same as you.. I have a script in "ExecStartPost" , which runs "brctl"

Comment: Could you provide more details about the solution? I created a tap device using SoftEther and I did try the `brctl addbr br0 tap_tapdevice` command but it doesn't do anything. In fact, if I do `brctl addif enp1s0` after that I lose my network connection completely.

Comment: is the interface up? Thanks to "Douglas Manley", i added successfully the following to my systemd service file: `ExecStartPost brctl addbr br0` `ExecStartPost brctl addif enp1s0 tap_tapdevice` `ExecStartPost ip link set dev br0 up`

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it (ubuntu 18.04/20.04):

(1) Set up a bridge (`br0`) using netplan config and add the NIC interface only to the bridge (in `/etc/netplan`).

(2) Add `tap_softether` to the bridge in start up script (in `/etc/init.d`).

`brctl addif br0 tap_softether`  # adding tap device after it's up.

(3) Results:
Download on openvpn went up from 1 Mbps (on physical bridge) to 100 Mbps (on tap bridge).

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue. Hopefully my experience helps someone.
I had a bridge br0 with several NICs, softether connecting to br0 using a veth pair (veth_se-veth_sebr) to avoid using dedicated NIC and still be able ping server.
on a 100MB down, 10MB up I was seening 0.5Mdown/6MB up.

I turned off TSO on both ends of veth.

- ethtool -K veth_sebr tso off
- ethtool -K veth_se tso off

download speed now 80MBs, upload 6MBs

Comment: quote "If TSO is enabled on the transmission path, the NIC divides larger data chunks into TCP segments. If TSO is disabled, the CPU performs segmentation for TCP/IP." -- so why disabling it improves speed ? I tested and confirm it helps but how ?